Could not establish a connection to the queue manager. Channel not available (AMQ4870)
I have started using the IBM MQ recently. Never worked on this before. I have installed the IBM MQ in the linux server and client in the windows. When we are testing the queue manager, it starts well and after sometimes I am getting the below error.
enter image description here
When I check the linux box, the connections seem to be up but the MQ manager shows the above error. Once I restart the service, the MQ manager works well again. It is a repetitive issue. How to solve this issue?
I have tried restarting the service to establish the connection.

How are you testing? Have you written an application to connect to queue manager? If yes are you closing the queues that you have opened and closing connection properly by calling MQDISC.AMQ4870 error means the queue manager has reached max levels for the channel.

The image you link to shows MQ Explorer with a channel not available error. Which if you go to the online documentation shows that a MQRC_CHANNEL_NOT_AVAILABLE will have been thrown. There is already an excellent answer as to what that means here.
In short it looks like your client application is misbehaving and not releasing the connection. As you are not sharing any code it is impossible to tell you where in your code, although you should read the AMQERR01.LOG files on both client and queue manager machines, to determine the cause.
